# How do I install cudf using pip?

Tags: pip, python-3.6, cudf

I wanted to accelerate pandas on my GPU so I decided to use `cudf` library. Please do suggest other libraries(if any).

I tried to install `cudf` using pip by `pip3.6 install cudf-cuda92`. The pip version is 19.2.3(latest).

When I run `pip3.6 install cudf-cuda92` on my cmd it says:

```
Collecting cudf-cuda92
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cudf-cuda92 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cudf-cuda92
```

Comment: What is your operating system? `cudf` is only available on linux

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the cuda support version of your GPU

```
nvidia-smi
```

[image]

2. Get the download command for the supported cuda version from https://docs.rapids.ai/install

[image: This is where you select the requirments to get the command]

3. Copy the command and execute

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing using `conda`.You can get a minimal conda installation with [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) or get the full installation with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).

Install and update cuDF using the conda command:

```
# CUDA 9.2
conda install -c nvidia -c rapidsai -c numba -c conda-forge -c defaults cudf

# CUDA 10.0
conda install -c nvidia/label/cuda10.0 -c rapidsai/label/cuda10.0 -c numba -c conda-forge -c defaults cudf
```

Find out more from [cudf.PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/cudf/)

Answer (score 2):

You can install with pip, but be aware that the cuda version dependency can be quite strict and may need to be matched to your cudf version.    Different cudf versions have been provided for this purpose, but they may lag behind latest.

e.g. I'm running cuda 10.0 so installed cudf with:

```
pip3 install cudf-cuda100
```

and then added a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d to point to /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64

(I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 2):

`cudf` pip install is officially  **NOT** supported nor maintained. Check out the [discussion on cudf github](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/285#issuecomment-518383671) and the official rapids [announcement](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/rapids-0-7-release-drops-pip-packages-47fc966e9472).

The way to go is either through conda or by building the source code.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
!pip install cudf-cu11==22.12 rmm-cu11==22.12 dask-cudf-cu11==22.12 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com/
```

https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/12762